# Ascii on TCP socket

Tags: java, network-programming, javadoc

Anyone could pass me an example of sending Ascii msg over TCP?(couldnt find example on the net)

thanks,

ray.

Comment: It is nearly unbelievable that you could not find *any* example in the WWW: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) of writing to and reading from an echoing server.

A simplified excerpt:

```
    Socket echoSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        echoSocket = new Socket("taranis", 7);
        out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                           + "the connection to: taranis.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String userInput;

while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(userInput);
    System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
}
```

Comment: he needs ASCII, any reader in such case is useless, just socket's input/output stream will do (no need to wrap 'em w/ BufferedXXX)

Comment: I disagree with bestsss on both arguments. Firstly, using a reader is safer (if one days he switches from ASCII to Unicode there will be no trouble). Secondly, using a buffered reader is necessary for speed (without buffering, you lose a lot of time due to constantly polling the socket). Lastly, the combination of both is fast, unicode compatible and provides handy methods (like readLine() rather than handling an array of bytes)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, I think this should work:

```
try (DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
    outToClient.write(stringMessage.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not stated in the original question is whether ASCII control codes have to handled.

While the accepted answer works for *printable* ASCII characters I've had problems (on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1) using it for strings containing ASCII control codes, especially strings containing any of the java newline "characters", e.g. VT, CR, LF,  etc.  A workaround is to send the string as bytes and convert it back to a string at the far end.

See my answer to this question for how to handle that situation.

[Reading Lines and byte[] from input stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149940/reading-lines-and-byte-from-input-stream)

and my closely related question and it's accepted answer:

[Need TCPIP client that blocks until a specific character sequence is received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34183493/need-tcpip-client-that-blocks-until-a-specific-character-sequence-is-receivee)