# error while sending a String from C client to Java server

Tags: java, c, sockets, datainputstream

I send an integer from a C client to a java server and it worked perfectly. But when i tried to do the same thing with a string i got and error
this is the client code to send the String

```
char clientString[30];

    printf("String to send : \n");

        if( send( to_server_socket, &clientString, sizeof( clientString ), 0 ) != sizeof( clientString ) )
        {
            printf( "socket write failed");
            exit( -1 );
        }
```

And the java code to read it

```
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
          String clientString=din.readUTF();
           System.out.println(clientString);
```

Error

> java.io.EOFException
>   at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:180)    at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:592)     at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:547)     at
>   ServiceRequest.run(ServiceRequest.java:43)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

EDIT :I tried using `din.readLine()`,I don't have the error anymore but if i type fffffff12 on the client i got fffffff12`?7E^Ê?h in the server

Comment: Good, we have the Java exception call stack, but for _what_ exception?

Comment: Also note that `&clientString` and `sizeof(clientString)` may not do what you expect them to. Please edit your question to include the declaration of `clientString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readUTF` doesn't just read bytes from a socket. It starts by reading the length of the string (as a 16-bit integer) and then reading the string. The problem is that what you send is not what is required for `readUTF` to work successfully.

As Joachim Pileborg noted, you are also sending the entire 30 bytes of `clientString` (including any remaining bytes that were not explicitly set). You should send it like this instead:

```
send(to_server_socket, clientString, strlen(clientString), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You send *all* of the data in the `clientString` array, no matter how long the input really is. Terminate the string properly and only send e.g. `strlen(clientString)` bytes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that on the client side you are writing ASCII string but on the server side you are reading UTF, try to read the data as ASCII, as well if possible please mention the exception that occurred. This method can raise two exceptions: 1- An IO Exception or 2- An EOF exception.

Comment: i should use readByte to read as ASCII ? i Tried readLine , if i type fffffff12 on the client i got fffffff12`?7E^Ê?h in the server

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773846/ascii-on-tcp-socket