# Need TCPIP client that blocks until a specific character sequence is received

Tags: java, tcp

I need a java 7 TCP/IP client that will block until it receives a user specified character sequence (in my case a message terminator/separator - this would automatically "chunk" the data into individual messages for further processing).  I expected that this would be very standard code freely available on the web - but so far no luck.

Complicating things, "chunking" the received data using standard line separators (e.g. readLine() in Oracle's KnockKnock Client), is not possible since those characters are valid data inside the messages. The message format is an international standard and can't be changed.

After trying a few things (see below) I'm wondering if I'm taking the right approach.  Is there a freeware example somewhere that I could draw on for inspiration?  Or perhaps a 
class meeting my needs already exists somewhere in the depths of "rt.jar" or elsewhere.  (BTW I used eclipse to take a look at rt.jar's contents - the huge number of packages/classes (according to http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.sun/jars/rt.jar.html?all=true JVM 6 contains 13200+ classes) makes a manual search impractical).

---

I've used Oracles example "KnockKnock" client as a starting point. My first thought was that all that would be necessary is to modify one line:

```
while ( (fromServer = in.readLine()) != null )
```

to something like:

```
while ( (fromServer = in.readLine( separator = UserSpecifiedRegExValue )) != null )
```

Unfortunately this extremely useful overloading/generalization of readLine() does not exist in Java.

Oracle's example works because readLine() blocks until it receives the line separator value on the TCP/IP link.  My thinking was that a generalized verson of readLine() would also block until it received the user specified character string (i.e. the message terminator) thus giving me exactly what I want.  Since that approach isn't available my next thought was to replace readLine() with a getNextMessage() function that would block until the user specified character string was received by TCP/IP.  Based on other posts I came up with this function:

```
static String getNextMessage( java.io.BufferedReader MessageSource, 
                              String                 EndOfMessage_RegEx ) 
{           
    try ( java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner( MessageSource ) ) 
    { 
        return s.useDelimiter( EndOfMessage_RegEx ).hasNext() ? s.next() : ""; 
    }
}
```

and tested it by emulating readLine(), passing in the O/S specific line separator, as done in this variant:

```
final static String  LineSeparator     = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );  // LineSeparator = ODOA (<CR><LF>) on Win7
final static String  MessageSeparator  = Pattern.quote( LineSeparator );          // MessageSeparator = 5C510D0A5C45 (the RegEx string "\Q<CR><LF>\E")
final static Pattern EndOfMessageRegEx = Pattern.compile( MessageSeparator );

static String getNextMessage( java.io.BufferedReader MessageSource ) 

// This function needs to block until a complete message (terminated by 
// "EndOfMessageRegEx") is received by TCPIP from the other machine.

{           
    try ( java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner( MessageSource ).useDelimiter( EndOfMessageRegEx ) ) 
    { 
        if ( s.hasNext() ) 
        {
            return s.next();
        } 
        else 
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately both versions always return the null string, immediately terminating my client - which makes sense if hasNext() does not block. (The hasNext() documentation says it "may"  - i.e. not guaranteed to - block.) How do I get the blocking effect?

Another problem I see with both versions is that they pointlessly recreate a scanner every time the function is invoked.

Or am I forced into using the much more primitive approach of creating a buffer, using .read() and searching for the specified character string instead?

---

SOLUTION: Moved to accepted answer

Comment: I'd just call `Scanner.next();`. Obviously you won't create a new `Scanner` every time, that would be crazy. How did you get this task when you're clearly new to Java?

Comment: Where would Scanner.next() be used?  In the controlling while loop statement? In getNextMessage()?  BTW, Java is not that new to me but I've never had to deal with TCP/IP before (my background is unusual these days - procedural, top-down design).  I was expecting that there would be a class that allows me to treat the TCPIP interface almost like a black box/library call.  Also, finding things in the JVM (like PushbackInput, see below) is close to impossible - it seems you have to know EVERYTHING in java (all 13000+ classes in the JVM) before you can do ANYTHING useful with the language.

Comment: @Kayman, thank you for the spark that allowed me to figure it out.  Relatively simple (as I thought it should be) once you see how to put everything together.  I've appended my solution to the question, if you see anything wrong, please point it out.  And would you please create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You should probably make your own answer (put the last part of your question in it) and accept that, it'll be better. As for pointers, you'll want to specify the encoding in your `InputStreamReader` to make sure it'll be the same in all platforms. Other than that it looks good. Glad to see you got it solved in a decent fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @kayman's suggestions, the solution has been moved here and improved to use InputStreamReader's character encoding option.  In my case the encoding is predetermined, you may need to look at using getEncoding() instead.

---

This code, combined with using Scanner's useDelimiter() and the \Q\E form of regex expression (see below), worked for me when I used the results of System.getProperty( "line.separator" ) as the user specified line separator:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
///------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class ZZ
{
    final static String  LineSeparator     = System.getProperty( "line.separator" ); //  ODOA (<CR><LF>) on Win7
    final static String  MessageSeparator  = Pattern.quote( LineSeparator );         //  5C510D0A5C45 = RegEx string "\Q<CR><LF>\E" on Win7
    final static Pattern EndOfMessageRegEx = Pattern.compile( MessageSeparator );
    final static String  CharacterEncoding = "US-ASCII";    // or UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO-8859-1, etc,

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void main( String[] args ) 
            throws IOException 
    {
        String hostName   = "localhost";  // = 127.0.0.1
        int    portNumber = 14576;                    

        try  (
            Socket         TcpipLink    = new Socket( hostName, portNumber );
            BufferedReader FromServer   = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( TcpipLink.getInputStream(), CharacterEncoding ) );
            Scanner        ReceivedData = new Scanner( FromServer ).useDelimiter( EndOfMessageRegEx );                              
        ) {                      
            String ReceivedMessage;
            while ( (ReceivedMessage = ReceivedData.next()) !=  null ) {
                 //Process the Inbound message 
            }           
            System.out.println( "Client fell out off message handler loop" ); // should never get here
        } 
        catch ( UnknownHostException e )  {
            System.err.println( "Don't know about host " + hostName );
            System.exit( 1 );
        } 
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            System.err.println( "Could not connect to " +  hostName + "on port" + portNumber );
            System.exit( 1 );
        }

        System.out.println( "Client exited" );

    }   // end function main()

}   // end class "ZZ"
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this InputStream derived from PushbackInputStream:

```
public static class TerminatorInputString extends PushbackInputStream {

    private String terminator;

    public TerminatorInputString(InputStream inputStream, String string) {
        super(inputStream, 256);
        terminator = string;
    }

    public String nextMessage() throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] data = new byte[8];
        int len = read(data,  0,  data.length);
        while(len > 0) {
            baos.write(data, 0, len);
            byte[] all = baos.toByteArray();
            int idx = baos.toString().indexOf(terminator);
            if(idx >= 0) {                  
                String message = baos.toString().substring(0,  idx);
                byte[] unread = new byte[all.length-idx-terminator.length()];
                System.arraycopy(all, idx+terminator.length(), unread, 0, unread.length);
                super.unread(unread);
                return message;
            }
            len = read(data,  0,  data.length);
        }
        baos.flush();
        return new String(baos.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

It reads until terminator is found, then skips terminator and continues after that. End of stream will close final message.

Test frame:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //System.in is a bad stream (if used in eclipse at least)
        // - it will only flush and make data available
        // on new line
        TerminatorInputString tis = new TerminatorInputString(System.in, "SCHWARZENEGGER");
        String message = tis.nextMessage();
        while(message != null) {
            System.out.println("MSG:>" + message + "<");
            message = tis.nextMessage();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With this input

```
oneSCHWARZENEGGERtwoSCHWARZENEGGERthreeSCHWARZENEGGER
```

produces this output:

```
MSG:>one<
MSG:>two<
MSG:>three<
```

Comment: Thanks for the mentioning that major pitfall in System.in, something like that I would have never expectedI.'ll certantly play around with this but the need for it t I fail to understand why such an obviously usgul class isn't part of the JVM.

Comment: Replace above with:Thanks for the mentioning that major pitfall in System.in -  it's something I would have never expected to be in what should be a very general package (a "surprise" when your background is with other languages, e.g. Fortran/Pascal/ADA). This is a version of the .read() method I alluded to so I'll certainly play around with it, then figure out how to "TCP/IP-ize" it and look at splicing it into our existing code.  However I fail to understand why we are forced to go into the weeds because such an obviously useful generalized TCPIP handler class isn't already part of the JVM.

Comment: @user1459519 Maybe it's not "obviously useful" to other people. This seems like the kind of thing you'd write for a school exercise, not a replacement for a real protocol in a production system.

Comment: @Kayaman: I agree with your second point (it hits the nail on the head).  Writing something is exactly what I wanted to avoid since it's in my interests to use a production level, generalized, fully debugged class if one exists (and I can find it) in the JVM.  It's abscene is just one example of general problem not unique to java: designers/implementers not taking a little extra time to see if something can be easily generalized (with a reasonable amount of effort) into something much more powerful.
P.S. An amusing test string once you realize why it was chosen.

Comment: @user1459519 What I meant was that a protocol based on string delimiters is quite naive compared to a business grade solution like [protocol buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers).

Comment: Thanks, @Kayman, I didn't know about them. I read the wiki, they look reasonable for new applications.  But for reasons in the just added "Background Details" section this approach may not work for us - especially given we have no control over the far end - and we're on a tight schedule due to a SNAFU situation.