# Sending ASCII character to server using Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to connect my computer with a device using Socket.

Using my code, I managed to connect to another device using socket.
The connection worked but the problem now is that the device that I am connected to have it's own SDK and it's in ASCII characters.
When I try to send in a command (from the SDK) using String, the code does not work, please advice.

```
String Address = txtAddress.getText();
    Socket MyClient;
    try {
        MyClient = new Socket(Address,9993);
        os = new DataOutputStream(MyClient.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(MyClient.getInputStream());
        this.main.showUserView();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         lble.setText("Don't know about host: hostname");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        lble.setText("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773846/ascii-on-tcp-socket)

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" is not very helpful. Please elaborate more. Is there any error? What's the error? Freeze? No error whatsoever and just followed by immediate exit?

Comment: Now there is no error but when i send the writebytes command over, the machine doesnt respond at all. But overall the whole system is connected already

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to send data using DatagramPacket?

```
int PORT = ## (port we are using for communication)

byte[] strBytes = myString.getBytes();

InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddressString);
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(strBytes, strBytes.length, address, PORT);
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.send(packet);
socket.close();
```